# If $\exists N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \le \beta$, $\forall n\ge N_1$ and $a_n \rightarrow A$ then $A \le \beta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $\exists N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \le \beta$,  $\forall n\ge N_1$ and $a_n \rightarrow A$ then $A \le \beta$

What I thought:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given

Since $a_n \rightarrow A$ then $\exists N_2$ such that $\forall n\ge N_2$:
$|a_n - A|<\epsilon$

This is equivalent to: $-\epsilon<a_n-A<\epsilon$

Thus: $A-\epsilon<a_n<\epsilon+A$

We can then write: $A-\epsilon<a_n\le \beta \leftrightarrow A-\epsilon\le\beta$

But I am not sure if a can do anything from here.
Any hints on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done: You have proved up to now:
$$ A - \epsilon \le \beta, \qquad \text{all } \epsilon > 0 $$
Suppose now, we have $\beta < A$. Let $\epsilon := \frac 12(A - \beta) > 0$, then 
$$ \beta + \epsilon = A - \epsilon < \beta $$
Contradiction. Hence $A \le \beta$.

NB: This argument holds (of course) in general: For any real numbers $a,b \in \mathbf R$ the relation $a \le b$ is equivalent to $a \le b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: But isn't $1/2(A-\beta)$ not necessarily greater than 0, since A and $\beta$ are not restricted to be positive?

Comment: Even if $A$ and $\beta$ are negative, if we assume $\beta < A$, this implies $A - \beta > 0$. (think of $A = -4$ and $\beta = -5$).

Comment: Oh yes! I see. One more question. I understand why $\beta + \epsilon = A - \epsilon$ and I see the contradiction, however I don't see how you got $A-\epsilon<\beta$

Comment: Nevermind, I got it!